# ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 609: Action App\Http\Controllers\ContactController@InsertQuery not defined.

Tags: php, forms, laravel, routes

contact.blade.php

```
{!!Form::open([ 'action'=>'ContactController@InsertQuery', 'method' => 'get', 'id' => 'contactform'])!!}
```

ContactController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request\ContactRequest;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\ontactModel;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function InsertQuery(){

    }
}
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get("/Contact", function(){
   return view('contact');
});
```

But it is showing above error and it i'm using below code in Route.php

```
Route::get("/Contact",[
  'uses' => 'ContactController@InsertQuery', 
  'as' => 'contact.submit'
]);
```

and in contact.blade.php `{!!Form::open([ 'route'=>'contact.submit', 'method' => 'get', 'id' => 'contactform'])!!}`

then it is not showing contact.blade.php form directly redirecting to controller.

Comment: Why don't you change the name of the route that uses the InsertQuery controller method

Comment: I changed but I think there was some problem with name of controller. @linktoahref

Comment: Why don't you update the latest code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there is some problem in name of function "InsertQuery". Because after changing name of function it is working.